# How can I add to the ascii value of a char letter?

Tags: c

so, lets say that a char contains the letter "a":

```
int main() {
int i=8;
char test2[2]="a"+i;
return 0;
}
```

I just want to add 5 to the value of that letter's ASCII value. So that test2 would contain "h", since ASCII value of h a ASCII value of a+8.

Is there a simple way to do this? I have tried googling this, and I would think this is a basic thing to do, but I am clearly missing an easy way to do this. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: You're adding i to the address of the first element of the string literal `"a"`. Try using the character constant `'a'` instead. You're also trying to initialize an array with a scalar value. Your compiler should be warning you about it, and if not, enable all warnings.

Comment: [Reading a good beginners book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) should be a good start.

Comment: `char test2[2]={'a'+i-1};`

Comment: Stop guessing and start reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add to a `char`, not the string:

```
char test2[2] = { 'a' + i, 0 };
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense now. Appreciate your help with this.

Answer (score 2):

`"a"` is not a character, but a string.  You need single quotes to works with individual characters.

```
int i = 8;
char c = 'a' + i;
printf("c=%c\n", c);
```

Output:

```
c=i
```

Answer (score 1):

In C, character holds an ACSII value (which is integer) by default. In your case, to make h out of a you have to do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
char test2 = 'a' + 7;
printf("%c\n\n", test2); // just check
return 0;
}
```

Comment: While `char` is a (`signed` or `unsigned`) integer type in C, encoding is _not_ ASCII by default; this is an implementation detail, and not specified by the Standard.

Comment: For example, some IBM systems used to use [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Binary_Coded_Decimal_Interchange_Code) instead of ASCII. Here, the characters of the Latin alphabet are not encoded in a contiguous sequence, causing some ASCII-reliant code to fail. This problem still crops up in the real world on legacy systems.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't compiled this, but wouldn't `(int)'a' + i` work?

A double quote isn't a `char`, its a string literal.

Comment: I'm not even sure the explicit cast is necessary, either.

Comment: Character constants have type int in C, so this'll cast an int as int.

Comment: I thought so. Thanks.